# Github Actions: using workflow_run based on new tags

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions, continuous-delivery

I have two workflows: CI (for continuous integration) and CD (for continuous delivery). Both are working fine individually. My goal is to run the CD workflow only when:

- A new tag like v1.1.1 is created on the master branch
- The CI workflow is finished

To achieve my goal I'm using the `workflow_run` event. These are the snippets of my workflows files:

ci.yml:

```
name: CI

on:
  push:
    tags: v[1-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+
    
  pull_request:
    branches: [develop, hotfix*]
```

cd.yml

```
name: CD

on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: [CI] 
    branches: [master]
    types:     
      - completed
```

The current behavior is: when a tag is created in the master branch only the CI workflow run. I've tried putting `tags: v[1-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+` in the `workflow_run` but the behavior is the same.

My question is: how can I achieve my goal? Is it possible?

Comment: Looks like there is no other way to do this than to duplicate the workflow you depends on (here "CI staging" and "CI production") and to filter by tags / branch in them instead.

Tried to find out if a if approach would work:
jobs:
      build:
         if: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.conclusion == 'success' }}
         runs-on: ubuntu-latest

But looks like the `workflow_run` object do not contain tags. If anyone finds out a way to log the entine event to inspect it, please leave a comment ;).

Answer (score 1):

According to [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_run) you can only use `branches` option and not `tags` for workflow_run so I'm afraid that's why your current setting doesn't work.

You have some alternatives though:

1. You can turn your CD workflow [into action](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/migrating-to-github-actions/migrating-from-gitlab-cicd-to-github-actions) and run it as part of your CI with condition:
   `.github/actiond/cd/action.yml`:

```yaml
name: CD
description: Run CD
runs:
  using: composite
  steps:
    - run: echo "Success!"
      shell: bash
```

CI:

```yaml
name: CI

on:
  push:
    tags: v[1-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+
  pull_request:
    branches: [develop, hotfix*]

jobs:
  sucess:
    name: Log success
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - run: echo "Success!"
      - name: Run CD
        if: github.event_name == 'push' && contains(github.event.ref, '/tags/')
        uses: ./.github/actions/cd
```

2. Have it as a separate job that is dependant on CI job using `needs` option

Converting it to action makes for better encapsulation IMO although requires some work.

Answer (score -3):

You need to put "" around the name of the triggering workflow in `cd.yml`:

```
name: CD

on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: ["CI"]
```

Comment: This workflow isn't working as expected for me, could you please post a full (basic) example ci.yml and cd.yml? Thanks

Comment: The YAML syntax in the question is fine. There are no missing quotes.